# Is the algorithm of calculating SEs of beta coefficients calculated by the nlme gls finally fixed?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, standard-error, generalized-least-squares

I can read here:
https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~davidian/st732/examples/dental_pa.R
and here:
https://math.unm.edu/~luyan/stat57918/week14.pdf

that:

> WARNING:  There is a MISTAKE in gls(), and it DOES NOT calculate the
>   model-based sampling covariance matrix of betahat correctly! Thus, the
>   model-based standard errors that gls() reports are ever so slightly
>   "off" from the correct values.  MOREOVER, gls() does not calculate the
>   robust sandwich covariance matrix, so does not offer the option of
>   getting robust (or empirical) standard errors.  The function
>   robust.cov below will compute correct model-based standard errors
>   along with robust sandwich standard errors.

Does anyone know, if this is fixed? Is this possible, that a package as old as nlme and used by thousands of users returns still incorrect values and misguides the users? Or is this fixed?

In your opinion, should be the function proposed in the linked materials

```
#  Function to compute correct and robust standard errors from a gls()
#  model object

library(Matrix)
library(magic)

#  u <- model object from fit, m <- total # individuals

robust.cov <- function(u,m){
  form <-  formula(u)
  mf <- model.frame(form,getData(u))
  Xmat <- model.matrix(form,mf)
  Vlist <-  as.list(1:m)
  for (i in 1:m){
    Vlist[[i]] <- getVarCov(u,individual=i,type="marginal")
  }
  V <- Reduce(adiag,Vlist)
  Vinv <- solve(V)
  Sig.model <- solve(t(Xmat)%*%Vinv%*%Xmat)
  resid <- diag(residuals(u,type="response"))
  ones.list <- lapply(Vlist,FUN=function(u){matrix(1,nrow(u),ncol(u))})
  Ones <- Reduce(adiag,ones.list)
  meat <- t(Xmat)%*%Vinv%*%resid%*%Ones%*%resid%*%Vinv%*%Xmat
  Sig.robust <- Sig.model%*%meat%*%Sig.model
  se.robust <- sqrt(diag(Sig.robust))
  se.model <- sqrt(diag(Sig.model))
  return(list(Sig.model=Sig.model,se.model=se.model,Sig.robust=Sig.robust,se.robust=se.robust))
}
```

or methods listed in this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clubSandwich/clubSandwich.pdf still used when dealing with GLS?

EDIT: I just checked. It seems gls still calculates SEs that aren't compliant with SAS. But are consistent with lme, lme4 and glmmTMB.

Using the clubSandwich R package with type of robust estimation "CR0" gives results identical to those obtained with the presented above  robust.cov() function.

The Kenward-Roger SEs for lme4 and gls(), in my case were only very slightly different, and far from those from robust estimation.

```
                 GLS_original GLS_corrected GLS_KR_Lava2 lmer_original lmer_Sandwich
(Intercept)         0.8215916     0.7537342    0.8441051     0.8215916     0.7537342
Program2            1.0905540     1.0028205    1.1204378     1.0905540     1.0028205
Program3            1.1022808     0.9526228    1.1324858     1.1022808     0.9526228
Timef4              0.3867933     0.2142392    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.2142392
Timef6              0.3867933     0.3408973    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.3408973
Timef8              0.3867933     0.4023248    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.4023248
Timef10             0.3867933     0.5517639    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.5517639
Timef12             0.3867933     0.6185211    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.6185211
Timef14             0.3867933     0.6371859    0.3973924     0.3867933     0.6371859
Program2:Timef4     0.5134169     0.2743518    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.2743518
Program3:Timef4     0.5189377     0.2896523    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.2896523
Program2:Timef6     0.5134169     0.4411397    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.4411397
Program3:Timef6     0.5189377     0.4069225    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.4069225
Program2:Timef8     0.5134169     0.5008398    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.5008398
Program3:Timef8     0.5189377     0.5407081    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.5407081
Program2:Timef10    0.5134169     0.6413605    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.6413605
Program3:Timef10    0.5189377     0.6832411    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.6832411
Program2:Timef12    0.5134169     0.7148875    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.7148875
Program3:Timef12    0.5189377     0.7409071    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.7409071
Program2:Timef14    0.5134169     0.7529247    0.5274858     0.5134169     0.7529247
Program3:Timef14    0.5189377     0.7729042    0.5331578     0.5189377     0.7729042
```

As we can see, Sandwich is completely opposite to KR (with regard to the uncorrected one)

Now, I'm wondering, which one to choose: the original SEs, the robust sandwich SEs or the Kenward-Roger SEs...

---

EDIT: OK, I got the answer, I think. It's the difference between model and empirical SE. By default, all linear models in R return the model-based ones, and GEE (depending on a library) - the sandwich (empirical) SE.

This is software independent topic.
People analyze similar issue within/between SAS and Stata.
http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~wguan/class/PUBH7402/notes/lecture9_GEEvsRE_linear.pdf
https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/xtgee-versus-proc-genmod/

The advice is to use model-based SEs for smaller number of clusters. One can also use the Sandwich with appropriate correction. There are many off them, but Morel et al. seems to be the most common correction used.

I'm still not sure which one to report, so I will report both, and make inference based on the more conservative approach, which seems safer as long as the type 1 error is worse.

Comment: 1. Compliance with SAS is not a development goal for R package maintainers. 2. Where does the documentation of the `summary.gls` function claim that robust standard errors are reported? 3. Instead the documentation says that "approximate standard errors" are provided.

Comment: This is why I asked people who have knowledge, to tell me, if this claim that SAS does it "right" is true, and if so, why the GLS does not. I am a simple R user, who read something on a statistical course and try to get some information. I don't go into "politics", I just want to know if I can rely on the results, if asked by a reviewer. The links I provided inform where is the discrepancy (in using appropriate degrees of freedom), I have no knowledge to judge if it's good or not. So, instead of telling me that this not a goal, please tell me whether it's worrying or not. Thank you.

Comment: All the more so as the algorithm seems to apply also to lme and lmer, so it's clearly visible this kind of thinking is more common in R.

Comment: Estimating "correct" degrees of freedom for fixed effects of mixed models is AFAIK an unsolved problem (and possibly unsolvable). If you don't want to go full Bayesian, the best you can do is bootstrapping or approximate p-values.

Comment: I know the long term issue, I only wanted to know, if the algorithm for GLS is erroneous (totally wrong) or only "incompliant" with SAS due to conscious choice - it seems it's model based and SAS uses empirical one.

Comment: Upvoted for combination of excellent question and follow-up discussion.

Comment: If you think that you have found the answer, please post it as a formal answer to your question.